# Why am I getting "permission denied " while installing xampp?

Tags: 14.04, xampp

I'm entering the commands to install xampp, but I'm getting access denied. How to resolve it?

```
$ cd ~/Downloads
Downloads$ sudo su
Downloads# sudo chmode 777
sudo: chmode: command not found
Downloads# sudo chmode 777xampp-linux-x86-5.6.30.1-installer.run
sudo: chmode: command not found
Downloads# sudo chmode 777 xampp-linux-x86-5.6.30.1-installer.run
sudo: chmode: command not found
Downloads# ./ xampp-linux-x86-5.6.30.1-installer.run
bash: ./: is a directory
Downloads# ./xampp-linux-x86-5.6.30.1-installer.run
bash: ./xampp-linux-x86-5.6.30.1-installer.run: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `chmod` instead of `chmode`

Comment: 2 seconds to slow ;) But yeah that should be it

Comment: Anyway should be enough actually to use `chmod +x` instead of using `777`